# Flutter & Firestore: app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy Error

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have a flutter Project with `flutter_local_notifications` dependency.

When trying to add any **Firebase dependency** and compile for android I get this:

> D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

Any ideas how to address that?

Answer (score 2):

By [this issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/103#issuecomment-390775206), I would say you need to set:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in your `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue the following works:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

in **gradle.properties** file.

and

```
subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in **build.gradle** file on the project level.